# LCD Screen on GPIO

Tags: gpio, lcd

I have recently purchased a small LCD screen to use with my Raspberry Pi, as shown below.

[image: Front of the screen]
[image: Back Of the screen]

I tried attaching it to 16 of the GPIO headers, connected to its 16 (usable) pins. I found [this forum post](http://www.picaxeforum.co.uk/entry.php?142-Kemo-Electronic-S043-LCD-LED-Displays-Lucky-Bags-Blog-2-VFD-and-bare-glass-LCDs), and (using the pinout provided) tried to get the display working. I switched several of the connections on and off trying grid-references from the pinout and just some random combinations... and there was no apparently pattern to the results.

I have no previous experience of LCDs, and cannot find any help at all for this particular screen. Is there a way I can control the screen directly from the Pi, or do I need some sort of IC or driver thingy in the middle? Please explain how this screen could work and tell me what I need to do to get it to do that. If I need to buy anything then provide a link, as I have nothing but this screen, some resistors, and a bunch of LEDs (alongside with the Pi of cause).

Screen part no:

```
DGL-0401YG-4EH
BLG0126-01
```

Comment: This device is not that simple (see for example: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/96063/1729) , requires toggling the pins continuously in a specific sequence to display anything. In any case, if you are new to this, using an unknown surplus LCD without a datasheet is a guarantee for a bad time. IMO  best to find an LCD with a datasheet, or even better one designed for the raspberry pi to experiment with. Unless you have a particular need to use **this exact LCD** its going to just be a giant time sink with little reward in my experience

Comment: @crasic There is some info in the forum post I linked to, but I don't know if it is enough for me to be able to run the screen. It includes a pinout, but I don't know what the sequence is that I have to toggle the pins in. Scroll down to the _2-4 LCD with pins_ section to see this.

Comment: @crasic That link you provided is the same screen!!! After looking at that, I think I need to buy one of [these microchips](http://www.microchipdirect.com/product/PIC16F1939), correct?

Comment: a `PIC` is just another type of 8-bit microcontroller like the `ATMEGA` chip on the arduino platform. It is useful only because that particular type has a LCD Driver Built In to. I chose that link because they discuss your partcular LCD, which is not a standard part so the only way to find information on it is random posts with peoples findings, rather than a real datasheet that would actually  help you interface it.